# Права на файл www-data на хостинге

Tags: php

На хостинге есть несколько файлов. Все имеют owner'a - "www-data", кроме одного, owner, у которого "nickname". Файлы на сайт заливаются из svn, а т.к. один файл нельзя перезаписать, происходят ошибки и файл надо вручную от этого owner'a заливать. Как сменить владельца с "nickname" на "www-data". Просто удалить файл и залить из svn нельзя, т.к. это происходит раз в 10 минут и не зависит от меня. А на 10 минут вырубать сайт для меня не позволительно. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chown в командной строке
```

Но при условии что у тебя есть ssh доступ и можешь сменить пользователя.

**//UPD**

```
# chown root /path/file.name
```